# QT: reject() closing whole app? Why?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2005

I'm running a QT app (VS2005) and have spawned a dialog from that app, but if I add a cancel button to that dialog with a reject() slot then yes, the dialog closes and returns the correct result but my whole app closes down as well.

This is annoying me and I can't find any hint as to why; any suggestions gratefully recieved

Comment: Have located issue; I'd missed the ": QDialog(parent, flags)" from the end of the constructors.

Thanks for the suggestion Thomi, this is going to be helpful with some other stuff anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps look at setting this:

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop

to false?

If that doesn't work, make sure you haven't got any signal / slot connections you may have forgotten about.